# Static property and constructor injection potential memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a bootstrapper task that runs on startup. I get an object, a singleton, injected into the constructor and then I set a static property to this object. Would this cause the boostrapper class to not be GCd?

```
public class BootstrapperTask : IStartupTask
{
    public BootstrapperTask
    (
        ILocaliser<string> languageLocaliser
    )
    {
        //here I set the static property
        Local.LanguageLocaliser = languageLocaliser;
    }
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // perform startup actions
    }
}
```

The singleton `ILocaliser<string>` gets injected into the constructor, `languageLocaliser`, which references the object in DI container. `Local` static class then references `languageLocaliser` which is part of `BootstrapperTask`. Because `Local` is static and will live till end of app, does that mean `BootstrapperTask` cannot be cleaned up due to `Local` pointing to `languageLocaliser`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a reference to your instantiated class,

```
Local.LanguageLocaliser = languageLocaliser // reference
```

Then the reference count will be greater than `0`, and therefor wont be garbage collected